# QT file open and close

Tags: qt, file, methods

Here is the declaration of my QFILE class.

```
class AbsFileHandler
    {

    public:
        QFile absfile;
        QString absfilename;
        QTextStream absstream;
        void CreateAbsFile();
        void CloseAbsFile();

        AbsFileHandler()
        {

        }
        ~AbsFileHandler()
        {
        }

    };
```

And its method construction

```
void AbsFileHandler::CreateAbsFile()
    {

        absfilename = absfilename + '.abs';
        absfile(absfilename);

        if (!absfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
            qDebug() << absfile.errorString();
        else
            qDebug() << "It worked";

    }

void AbsFileHandler::CloseAbsFile()
    {
        absfile.close();
    }
```

I am having error in the absfile(absfilename); statement. Why was the error in this statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In this line

```
absfile(absfilename);
```

you try to invoke `QFile::operator()(QString)` on `absfile` object, but `QFile` class doesn't have this method. I suppose you want to set name for file before opening it, so you should use `setName` (Qt3), or `setFileName` (qt4/5) methods of QFile. Change it

```
absfile.setFileName(absfilename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have gotten error because, it looks like, you wanted to call a constructor of `QFile` class like

```
QFile file(filename);
```

But problem is that you have declared object `QFile` before and it was initialized in constructor when object of `AbsFileHandler` class was initialized.

```
AbsFileHandler obj; // in this case default constructor AbsFileHandler::AbsFileHandler() will be called which empty (not empty actually)
```

`AbsFileHandler::AbsFileHandler() {}` will initialize all objects in your class by calling their default constructors like:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : {} //Actually it means this:
    // A() : f(QFile()) {} 
private:
    QFile f;
};
```

So

```
absfile(absfilename);
```

doesn't mean that the constructor `QFile::QFile(const QString &name)` will be called but the `QFile::operator()(QString)` which undefined in class `QFile`.
Thats why you've got error.